# Alguna manera de cargar web externa sin iframe o embed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy creando una especie de navegador pero el problema es que tanto **google** como **yahoo** entre otros no permiten cargar sus web en iframe **“X-Frame-Options”**

**¿Qué puedo hacer?** tal vez dejar navegar en otra ventana pero no tendría sentido porque cómo se realizaría otra búsqueda o se devolvería hacia atrás sin nisquiera tener un div fijo.

```js
function search() {
var path = "https://www.google.com/search?q=";
var search = document.getElementById("search").value;
document.getElementById("result").src = path + search;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Buscador</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Usa el buscador</h2>
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Quiero buscar...">
<button onclick="search()">Buscar</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<iframe id="result" src=""></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si el dueño del contenido no quiere que se muestre embebido, no deberías intentar saltarte esa política. Como mínimo es algo grosero; en el peor de los casos, te pueden bloquear por hotlinking

Answer (score 1):

Google no permite que muestres su contenido embedido.

Tienes dos formas de mostrar los resultados de google en tu página web:

**La primera** sería utilizando https://cse.google.es/cse, una vez crees un buscador (puedes poner cualquier URL de tu propiedad en el campo), tienes que acceder a `Editar motor de búsqueda > Configuración` y activar `Buscar en toda la Web`

**La segunda** (la cual no creo que sea tu objetivo) es, si estás haciendo una especie de "navegador" integrado, implementar un proxy en tu servidor al estilo de https://www.hidemyass.com/es-es/proxy, con ello podrías crear un `<iframe>` que llamase a tu servidor, y este procesaría la petición de la forma que tu desees. Incluso podrías mostrar el contenido directamente en un `<div>`